# requestAnimationFrame with easing to resize a DIV in IE 9+ (without jQuery or CSS3)

Tags: javascript, animation

I've found and read a slew of articles on `requestAnimationFrame` and easing and javascript animations but I'm having trouble putting it all together to do what I need. Honestly, I'm not even sure where/how to start. Plus a lot of the articles I've read contradict each other or show so many variations/options that I'm not sure which to pick.

I've got a `div` with `margin: 10px` and I want a smooth animation with easing to `margin: 0`.

My biggest issue is I need this to work on an OOB SharePoint 2010 site which means I cannot use CSS3 or jQuery and it has to work with IE 9.

```
<div id="box" style="margin: 10px;">test</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// these are the functions I need help with; not sure where/how to start
document.getElementById("box").onmouseenter = function(){}; // smooth animation to make margin = 0
document.getElementById("box").onmouseleave = function(){}; // smooth animation to make margin = 10

</script>
```

I'm not looking for anyone to tell me how to do it. I'm just hoping someone can point me in the right direction of some good articles on the subject. I'm not finding any that help me...

Comment: [Please post some code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ankit: I did but it's rather bare. I really can't figure out where/how to start.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan you don't seem to have tried anything in using `requestAnimationFrame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```js
document.getElementById("p").onmouseover=function(){
    
    function animate(margin,el) {
        el.style.margin=margin+"px";
        if (parseInt(el.style.margin)>0) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){animate(margin-1,el)});
        }
    }
    animate(10,this);
}
document.getElementById("p").onmouseout=function(){
    
    function animate(margin,el) {
        el.style.margin=margin+"px";
        if (parseInt(el.style.margin)<10) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){animate(margin+1,el)});
        }
    }
    animate(parseInt(this.style.margin),this);
}
```

```html
<p id=p>I am a working demo</p>
```

PS: convert `onmouseover` to `onmouseout` and convert `onmouseout` to `mouseleave`